# What does each site of a vanilla 9.1 installation do?

Tags: solution-architecture

I just installed a Vanilla 9.1 instance as part of my upgrade process. I used the XP Scaled Topology, as I will need some of its features.

After installation, I found the following sites in IIS:

[image]

I can guess some of them - cd, cm, identityserver - but I'm at a loss for the others.

**Question**

What is the function of the .collection, .ma, .mareporting, .prc, .processingEngine, .refdata, .rep, .reporting, .search websites in Sitecore 9.1?

Comment: All the roles are described here https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/roles-overview.html . I don't think copying that amount of content from official Sitecore documentation site is ok with their copyrights, so I will not include this as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are mostly self-explanatory, but here is the list of suffixes with the role names/descriptions:

- ***.cm**: Content management server
- ***.cd**: Content delivery server
- ***.collection**: The xConnect collection server, collects contact and interaction data
- ***.identityserver**: New in 9.1, this is the new Identity Server used for logging into the various other Sitecore admin pages
- ***.ma**: Marketing Automation service
- ***.msreporting**: Marketing Automation reporting server
- ***.prc**: xDB Processing Service
- ***.processingEngine**: xDB Processing Engine
- ***.refdata**: Reference Data Service, Reference data includes things like event definitions.
- ***.rep**: xDB Reporting
- ***.reporting**: xDB Reporting Service
- ***.search**: xConnect Search Indexer

For more detailed information about each role, the Sitecore documentation has a lot here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/roles-overview.html

Comment: Thank you Richard. As for the two xConnect instance, does their presence implies that xConnect is already installed as part of the XP1-SingleDeveloper.ps1 script?

Comment: Yes, that script should install an xConnect instance IIRC.